# Spring 4 MVC и log4j2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, log4j2

Пытаюсь настроить логирование в `Spring 4 MVC` через `log4j2`, но ни в консоль ни в файл логи не пишуться. В настройках `log4j2` поставил вывод информации его инициализации на уровень `DEBUG` и было видно что конфигурация подтягивается. Контроллер `Spring` работает, проверено на `System.out.println()`. В гугле находил несколько вариантов интеграции `log4j2` в `spring`, но ни один из них не помог.

---

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/config/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--<welcome-file-list>-->
    <!--<welcome-file>/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp</welcome-file>-->
<!--</welcome-file-list>-->

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/view/error/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="INFO">
    <properties>
        <property name="string_log">%-23d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}[%-5p] %-42l %m%n</property>
    </properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern></pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="file" fileName="/home/bleser/logs/working.log" filePattern="/home/bleser/logs/%d{dd-MM-yy}/working-%d{dd-MM-yy}.log" immediateFlush="false">
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="20" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
            <PatternLayout pattern="" charset="UTF-8"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="net.bleser" level="INFO" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="file"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

**POM Dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1211</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atteo.moonshine</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b04</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
 static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(UserController.class.getName());

    @Qualifier("userService")
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String main(Model model){
        log.info("log");
        model.addAttribute("user",new User());
        User user = new User(1,"test","test");
        model.addAttribute("users",user);
        return "/index";
    }
 }
```

Comment: А где у Вас log4j2.xml подтягивается? По коду не видно.

Comment: В контроллере `static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(UserController.class.getName());` он начинает искать файлы `log4j2.xml .json .properties `

Comment: покажите структуру проекта, где у вас лежит log4j2.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Случайно нашел причину по которой не выводились логи.
Все было из за того что в файле конфигурации не был прописан `PatternLayout` для файла и консоли:

```
<PatternLayout>
    <pattern></pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

---

```
<PatternLayout pattern="" charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Для того что бы все заработало нужно прописать:

```
<PatternLayout>
    <pattern>${string_log}</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

---

```
<PatternLayout pattern="${string_log}" charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для спринга 4.1.1, log4j 2.4.1 (2 года назад) решал так

```
<bean id="logging" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
   <property name="targetClass" value="com.хххх.spring.ХLog4j2Configurer" />
   <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
   <property name="arguments">
      <list>
         <value>${appFolder}/conf/log4j2.xml</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

бин :

```
public class ХLog4j2Configurer {
/** Extension that indicates a log4j XML config file: ".xml" */
public static final String XML_FILE_EXTENSION = ".xml";

public static void initLogging(String location) throws FileNotFoundException, Exception {
    String resolvedLocation = SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders(location);
    URL url = ResourceUtils.getURL(resolvedLocation);
    if (resolvedLocation.toLowerCase().endsWith(XML_FILE_EXTENSION)) {
        Object ctx = LogManager.getContext();
        if (ctx instanceof AsyncLoggerContext){
            System.out.println("Full async Log4j2 detected! See JVM prop:"
                    + " -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector");
            AsyncLoggerContext asyncCtx = (AsyncLoggerContext)ctx;
            asyncCtx.setConfigLocation(url.toURI());
        }else{
            Configurator.initialize("app", ХLog4j2Configurer.class.getClassLoader() , url.toURI());
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not found log4j2.xml config !");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: К сожалению данный метод у меня не сработал.